# Formula to count cells in a range that match any value in cells in another range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I am looking for a formula that will count the number of cells in a range (say A1:A5) whose values match any of the values of another range (say B1:B3).

Edit:  I am also looking for a formula that doesn't break randomly.  See bottom.*

If A1:A5 is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

and B1:B3 is:

```
3
4
8
```

the answer should be:

```
2
```

since A3 and A4 match something in B1:B3.

I expected the method shown here to work:
https://exceljet.net/formula/count-total-matches-in-two-ranges

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(range1,range2))
```

...but it doesn't.  Maybe that's because the range sizes are not the same?

```
=COUNTIF(range1,range2)
```

also doesn't work.

(My second range of cells is also on another sheet, but I can't imagine that would matter.)

Seems like there should be a simple formula for this kind of thing!

*Edit:

I tried the formula above a 2nd time, for the trivial example I gave, and this time it worked.  The formula is **unreliable**, though.  It can fail for some unknown reason as shown below.  It sometimes fails to read the 2nd COUNTIF range, and from testing today it seems to fail if there is no outer SUMPRODUCT.  Why would an outer formula element matter??

With just the COUNTIF part...
[image: With just the COUNTIF part...]

...it fails (and returns 0 instead of the expected 1).
[image: ...it fails (and returns 0 instead of the expected 1).]

With the *exact same formula fragment* (unless my eyes deceive me) wrapped in an outer SUMPRODUCT()...
[image: With the exact same formula fragment (unless my eyes deceive me) wrapped in an outer SUMPRODUCT()...]

...it works.  Why the difference??
[image: ...it works. Why the difference??]

Comment: Perhaps count matches.

Comment: I would like to accept an answer, but I'm torn.  VBasic2008's has a lot of good background information and 3 solutions but doesn't cover the fact that the original formula can work.  Mayukh Bhattacharya's does cover the original formula but doesn't cover the fact that it works *despite* the fact that a part of it (the COUNTIF inner part), when isolated, *doesn't* work.

Comment: I would like to accept an answer that covers the above and points out the actual stumbling blocks as I now understand them:  (I can't believe how many pitfalls there are for what seems like a simple task.)

Comment: (1) That COUNTIF doesn't act in a *composable* way.  (It produces a different result when alone vs wrapped in a SUMPRODUCT.  Completely unexpected, and 'trap' is a good word for it (just a different problem than the trap mentioned in one of the answers).  When I build a formula I should be able to piece it together from the inside out and usually do, getting inner functions to work properly before adding outer functions.)

Comment: (2) That the COUNT(MATCH) approach mentioned in a comment here and in one of the answers only works if entered as an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter).

Comment: (3) That there is strange inconsistency with COUNTIF, unpredictably deciding to evaluate an array as all its values or a single value:   With 'Evaluate Formula', I see =COUNTIF(A1:A5,Sheet1!B1:B3), when entered as a normal formula with Enter (Excel 2010 BTW) goes to =COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,3). It turns the second range into single number for some reason (which just happens to be one of the ones in the first range)! Very strange but of course it yields 1. =COUNTIF(AM8:AM373, main!D137:main!D146), when entered as a normal formula with Enter, goes to =COUNTIF($AM$8:$AM*373,#VALUE!) (and then yields 0)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does matches please refer the image below,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,$B$1:$B$3))
```

or

You may try this formula, as well,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$1:$A$5,$B$1:$B$3,0)))
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

Comment: Thanks for pointing me back to the original formula I was trying.  Turns out it works /sometimes/!  I've edited my question with that fallout.  Seems like some kind of bug.

Comment: I just tried your 2nd suggested formula and /it too/ suffers from the same problem!  The formula as-is works, but if the outer SUMPRODUCT() is stripped away it suddenly has trouble reading ranges and fails.  What is going on?

Comment: @A.M. sorry for the late response, could you share a one-drive link, have you tried the one suggested by VBasic2008 Sir, the second of mine & sir's as well are same, that should be working

Answer (score 2):

### Count Matches

As Solar Mike mentioned in the comments: *Perhaps count matches*.

```
=COUNT(MATCH($A$1:$A$10,$B$1:$B$10,0))
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$1:$A$10,$B$1:$B$10,0)))
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$10,$A$1:$A$10)>0))
```

**The `COUNTIF` Trap**

[image]

Comment: For me your 1st suggested formula fails (returns 0 instead of the expected 1 for that 'stage'), but the 2nd and 3rd succeed.  Is that supposed to be the case?  I'm trying to follow all of the examples in the spreadsheet in your image, and maybe that's the message you're giving, but I'm not sure.  Is it really somehow /not/ a bug for an Excel operation to fail in one context (stand-alone) but succeed in another (when nested within another operation)?  I've never seen anything like this.  I've updated my question with evidence of what looks to me like a bug.

Comment: All three solutions should give the same result. If you don't have Office 365, you need to enter the first as an array formula i.e. confirming it with `Ctrl,Shift+Enter`(intead of just `Enter`). The same goes for all the other formulas in the example i.e. only the `SUMPRODUCT` formulas don't need it. Let me know if that corrected your issue. The green formulas in column `E` should be the ones you'll be using.

Comment: OK, for the COUNTIF part alone, in my actual case, `=COUNTIF(AM8:AM373, main!D137:main!D146)`, entering as an array formula with `C-S-Ret` does work.  **And I guess SUMPRODUCT has special powers that force array formula entry for operations it wraps??** That answers a lot, thanks.  Why would that be required in my actual case but not for my trivial example though?  Actually even for a slightly less trivial example, with a range on another worksheet, it still doesn't need array formula entry!  `=COUNTIF(A1:A5,Sheet1!B1:B3)`  What is the difference I'm not seeing between those two formulas?

Comment: See the red part to understand what your `COUNTIF` formula returns. It's an array of zeros and numbers greater than zero. If you use CSE, then it will return the first element of the array. If you don't, who knows what is returned.

Comment: Note when I say entering the 1st formula as an array formula 'works' for me, I mean it yields 1 instead of 0, but it doesn't work for me in the sense of giving the final result (as if wrapped in SUMPRODUCT), which in my case would be 10.  I'm happy with that, and maybe that's what you mean.  Just wanted to be clear.

Comment: There still something fishy here.  With 'Evaluate Formula', I see `=COUNTIF(A1:A5,Sheet1!B1:B3)`, when entered as a normal formula with `Enter` (Excel 2010 BTW) goes to `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,3)`.  It turns the second range into *single number* for some reason (which just happens to be one of the ones in the first range)!  Very strange but of course it yields 1. 
 `=COUNTIF(AM8:AM373, main!D137:main!D146)`, when entered as a normal formula with `Enter`, goes to `=COUNTIF($AM$8:$AM*373,#VALUE!)` (and then yields 0).  I can't for the life of me see why those two formulas would act differently.

Comment: I do in my actual use case, but I tried replacing the `2` in my trivial example above with `-` and it didn't affect the result.

Comment: @A.M.: I have a feeling that you are commenting in the wrong area. These comments should be related to the image that has red and green cells. The title above the image says `The COUNTIF Trap` i.e. `COUNTIF` is just wrong: see the red part all the way down to the bottom to see how to make it work. Also, you may have not noticed that the first two formulas use `...(Range1,Range2)` while the third uses `...(Range2,Range1)` concluding that your `COUNTIF` formula is also wrong because the ranges are switched.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir, just realized by evaluating on `10K Rows` of data, you have researched & put in lot of effort thank you for the share!

Comment: @VBasic2008 Reversing the ranges results in the same output in my trivial example and in my real-world example because in both cases both ranges contain only unique values.  Reversing the ranges happens to result in the same output in your example(s) too, even though your ranges contain values, in this case more due to chance (unless you designed it that way).

Comment: I designed it that way: one value only in one of the sets, one value in both sets...